i was installing typescript on my macos m2 pro ...and after i pasted command ...i got some errors what should i do
npm i typescript
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /Users/ketaki_2004./.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/af/ce
npm ERR! errno EEXIST
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.nporg/typescript: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/ketaki_2004./.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/af/ce'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/keta./.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/af/ce
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
download and install typescript for angular js on my macos m2

What do you have under /Users/ketaki_2004./.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/af/ce ? Is there any chance one of those paths is a file where npm is expecting to create a directory? Can you try renaming some of the cache out of the way, or (if you're sure) deleting it?

Or you could just try --force as the error message suggests

You can give the folder permissions with:
sudo chown -R $USER /Users/ketaki_2004./.npm

And try deleting the existing files that may have been broken due to a partial installation with either --force as suggested by the error message or rm -rf /Users/ketaki_2004./.npm

But the error is EEXIST not ENOACCESS.

The same principle applies, because the file exists and the process has seemingly no permission to delete or overwrite it.
